# Oracle join select result

Tags: oracle

I 've got this problem:
I have a select statement, which is rather time consuming.
I have to join the result with itself.
I want to do something like this:

```
Select table1.*, table2.Consumption
from (heavy select statement) table1 left outer join 
(same heavy statement) table2
on table1."id" = table2."id" and table1."Year" -1 = table2."Year"
```

I don't want to catch the same data 2 times. I would rather like to do something like table1 table2. Is this possible?
I need this for an application, which executes querys but isn't able to use create or something like this, otherwise i would store the data in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a common table expression (CTE) and materialize the results of the heavy select statement:

```
WITH heavy AS ( SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */ ... (heavy select statemenet) )
Select table1.*, table2.Consumption
from heavy table1 left outer join 
heavy table2
on table1."id" = table2."id" and table1."Year" -1 = table2."Year"
```